# Keyboard shortcut to pause state updates in Windows 10 Task Manager?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, task-manager

Is there any way to temporarily pause status updates in the Windows 10 Task Manager with a keyboard shortcut? This would be akin to setting the `Update Speed` to `Paused`.

[image]

I'd like this ability so that I can get a good look at what is currently displayed without needing to dig into the menu every time and possibly missing the state I want to observe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Holding down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key on any tab of the Windows 10 Task Manager interface will temporarily pause UI updates and data recording until the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is released.

Comment: Is there any way to turn this behavior off, or at least map it to a different key?

Comment: @nog642 I don't believe there is. This is a hardcoded keyboard shortcut, AFAIK.